# Вернуть состояние select после запроса. Java Spring Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, post, select, thymeleaf

Изучаю web. Сделал странный калькулятор. Интересна только реализация.

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(){
            return "/home";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String home(
            @RequestParam(name = "first_number", defaultValue = "0") String first_number,
            @RequestParam(name = "second_number", defaultValue = "0") String second_number,
            @RequestParam(name = "operation", required = false) Operations operation,
            @RequestParam(name = "result_field", required = false, defaultValue = "") String result_field,
            Model model) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(result_field);

        String result = result_field + "\n";
        try {
            int first = Integer.parseInt(first_number);
            int second = Integer.parseInt(second_number);

            switch (operation) {
                case ADDITION: result = first + second + "";
                    break;
                case SUBTRACTION: result = first - second + "";
                    break;
                case MULTIPLICATION: result = first * second + "";
                    break;
                case DIVISION: result = first / second + "";
                    break;
                default: result = "Ошибка ввода данных";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = "Ошибка ввода данных";
        }

        builder.insert(0, result + "\n");

        model.addAttribute("operation", operation);
        model.addAttribute("first_number", first_number);
        model.addAttribute("second_number", second_number);
        model.addAttribute("result_field", builder.toString());
        return "home";
    }

}
```

Форма

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Калькулятор</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form  action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="first_number" placeholder="введите число" th:value="${first_number}">
    <select name="operation" th>
        <option selected disabled>Выберите операцию</option>
        <option value="ADDITION">Сложить</option>
        <option value="SUBTRACTION">Вычесть</option>
        <option value="MULTIPLICATION">Умножить</option>
        <option value="DIVISION">Поделить</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="second_number" placeholder="введите число" th:value="${second_number}"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Посчитать"><br><br><br>

    <p>Результат</p>
    <textarea rows="10" name="result_field" th:text="${result_field}"></textarea>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Скриншот страницы после 1-1:

[image: состояние select]

Как оставить состояние select в состоянии до отправки post-запроса? (например, на скриншоте должна быть выбрана операция SUBTRACTION)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Много разных путей, например использовать `th:if` [Simple conditionals: “if” and “unless”](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless) или `th:field` [Dropdown/List selectors binding](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dropdownlist-selectors), ну или вариации с параметрами `th:with`. В вашем случае код может выглядеть примерно так ... (или иначе)

```
<select name="operation">
    <option th:selected="${#strings.isEmpty(operation)}" selected disabled>Выберите операцию</option>
    <option th:selected="${#strings.equals(operation, 'ADDITION')}" value="ADDITION">Сложить</option>
    <option th:selected="${#strings.equals(operation, 'SUBTRACTION')}" value="SUBTRACTION">Вычесть</option>
    <option th:selected="${#strings.equals(operation, 'MULTIPLICATION')}" value="MULTIPLICATION">Умножить</option>
    <option th:selected="${#strings.equals(operation, 'DIVISION')}" value="DIVISION">Поделить</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Благодарю. Всё работает